# Where to define the Visual Studio 2010 AddIn installation path?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, add-in

When I try to install an VS 2010 Addin (for example Chirpy.vsi) it gets installed into the default AddIn folder. In my case it's P:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins.

However I want to change that folder to d:\My2010Addins. But I didn't find a Setting inside Visual Studio 2010 to point it to my d:\My2010Addins.

Where can I do that?

(I know I can set up Lookup Folders in Options -> Environment -> Add-in/Macro Security but that's not what i'm looling for)